# MongoDB Log Aggregation for Chartjs

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline

The collection consist of logs data.

## Logs

```
[
    { "Module": "Admin",
        "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Admin",
        "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Home",
        "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Admin",
        "UserEmail": "santa@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Contact",
        "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Contact",
        "UserEmail": "santa@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Admin",
        "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" },
    { "Module": "Home",
        "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
        "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00" }
]
```

## Expected Result

```
[
    {
        "Module": "Admin",
        "Count":4,
        "Logs": [
            {
                "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            },
            {
                "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            },
            {
                "UserEmail": "santa@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            },
            {
                "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Module": "Home",
        "Count":2,
        "Logs": [
            {
                "UserEmail": "ricky@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            },
            {
                "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Module": "Contact",
        "Count":2,
        "Logs": [
            {
                "UserEmail": "tony@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            },
            {
                "UserEmail": "santa@dne.com",
                "Completed": "2020-02-29T01:21:24.128+00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

need to have aggregation on the logs to get a usage count on the modules and user based time serties grpah for extra information . the expected result is going to be used to plot a line chart from chartjs.

looking for a aggregate pipeline to be build for the above problem in c# mongodb client.

Comment: That is just the thing to use `$group` for.

Comment: There is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccEfya), but it looks like you are wanting a mongodb specific solution.

Comment: this works great. just need to create a mongo aggregate pipeline from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation pipeline to get what you need :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Module",
      Count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      Logs: {
        $push: {
          UserEmail: "$UserEmail",
          "Completed": "$Completed"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Module: "$_id",
      Count: 1,
      Logs: 1
    }
  }
])
```

The $project stage is here only to rename _id to Module, you can remove it if it's not relevant.

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8yFVMFfqqPY)

Comment: Great. I wish I knew about mongo playground earlier. +1